# Script used for moving files between computers

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, operating-system, scp

I have two Ubuntu machines, `machineA` and `machineB`. I would like to write a script that periodically (e.g., every 15 minutes):

- copies ALL the files contained in a folder of `machineA` to a folder in `machineB` (via `scp`)
- deletes ALL the original files in the folder of `machineA`

Could you help me in doing this and/or give me hints in writing it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [cron job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) on one machine which does the scp to the other machine and deletes the corresponding files on itself.